# Thickbox, jQuery and ASPX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, thickbox

I have an ASPX MasterPage with jQuery and Thickbox references. I used Thickbox to display some helpful tips, i.e., product information using the inline HTML that define the class="thickbox."  Works on the links that are part of the MasterPages, however, when I create a new Web Form using the same MasterPage with the jQuery.js and Thickbox.css, the links won't pop up.  Here's an example:

```
<a href="help/htmlPage.html?height=400&width=600" title="Title of htmlPage" class="thickbox">IMAGE TAG</a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have `thickbox.js` included in those web forms? If yes, is it actually being loaded? Maybe you are using a relative path, and the directory has changed?

Use Firebug's net tab to verify that script files that are referenced are actually being loaded.

Comment: Script files are reference as shown in this screenshot I just took using Jing: http://screencast.com/t/MGE4MTQ3

Here's the code:  http://screencast.com/t/NDMwNDM5N

Comment: Hm. The only thing I can think of is to check the page's DTD. It says on the thickjbox page that a valid DTD is required for it to work. Other than that, no idea... Are there no error messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: Here's a video to show you that thickbox.css and jQuery.js fires up while debugging in VisualStudio.  Also, I recorded this video to you how the thickbox property fires up the popups, but it doesn't work for asn.net panel.  Let me know what you think.

Here's the video:  http://screencast.com/t/NTY3YTNhN2Mt

Comment: I'm not familiar with the world of MS IDEs and I may be mistaken, but at 0:54, QuoteForm.aspx seems to show three loaded scripts: mootools, all.something and recaptcha_ajax.js? Is thickbox.js not supposed to turn up there as well? Remember, you need thickbox.js on all pages for thickbox links to work.

Comment: thickbox.js is there.  Not sure why you didn't see it- Look at the video again!  It seems like the hiccup occurs when the <asp:panel loads.  It works on everywhere else of the QuoteForm.aspx.  Right?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I saw that wrongly. Can you try making the "My spouse" check box visible from the start (no triggering) and see whether it works then?